# Extension Method for permutations

Tags: c#, permutation

I got this snippet from an old SO question but have no Idea how its implemented. I'm new to interfaces so would someone please help?

I've placed it into a static class but i don't know how to call it so that it can generate a collection of permutations.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        // Ensure that the source IEnumerable is evaluated only once
        return permutations(source.ToArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> permutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var c = source.Count();
        if (c == 1)
            yield return source;
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
                foreach (var p in permutations(source.Take(i).Concat(source.Skip(i + 1))))
                    yield return source.Skip(i).Take(1).Concat(p);
    }
```

Comment: You should be more specific in asking of what you actually want. Do you want to know how to use that method? Or you want to clarify some details of its (their) internal behaviou? Or you just not sure about the methods definitions?

Comment: Interface are not complicated. They only contain a list of methods and/or fields. these fields and methods do not contain anycode. Think of it as a template form. when you create a class if you apply the interface you will be requested to code in the class those methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take your IEnumerable property (eg: listToPermutate):

```
var result = listToPermutate.Permutations();
```

You have to manually add the using to the static class.

Comment: It's also possible to call it just like static method: `var result = YourStaticClass.Permutations(listToPermutate);`

Comment: is this valid? I cant access a value from result once the method has run.    I was trying var result = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZY".Permutations(); wanted to access a permutation by using result[i]. is this valid?

Comment: You can't loop through an IEnumerable like this. You have to convert the IEnumerable to an actual Collection or List.

Answer (score 2):

As a reference, you should check out [MSDN Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).
You need to put this code in it's own static class.  The compiler will then know to treat the first method as an extension method to the Enumerable class because of the first parameter "this IEnumerable"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyExtensions
{
  public static class EnumerableExtensions
  {

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
      if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
      // Ensure that the source IEnumerable is evaluated only once
      return permutations(source.ToArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> permutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
      var c = source.Count();
      if (c == 1)
        yield return source;
      else
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            foreach (var p in permutations(source.Take(i).Concat(source.Skip(i + 1))))
                yield return source.Skip(i).Take(1).Concat(p);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the code you want to use the extensions from, you need to add a "using MyExtensions" to import the namespace where your extension methods reside.  Then just call it like

```
var resultList = list.Permutations();
```

If you have it setup correctly, you will even see the Permutations() function in the Intelesense window as you begin to type it.